# How to know major number during mknod manually?

Tags: linux-kernel, driver

I wrote a driver module, and compiled it into linux kernel. However, when I started the kernel, and planed to mknod in /dev, I realize I didn't know the major and minor number of my driver module. So, how to know its major and minor number of my own module?

Comment: Check `/proc/devices` and see if your device is listed there. The number in front of the name of your device is the major number.

Comment: Is it antique version of kernel? Otherwise why do you need *mknod* to be run manually? Use *udev* or other device manager in user space.

Comment: I register the device the **probe** function, so there is no my device in **/proc/devices**. Now, I found the **probe** function isn't called. Do you know how to call the **probe** function, making the **device name** and **driver name** the same? How can I know the device name?